viewModels not found in jetpack compose
I am trying to use a delegate function with viewModels, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to import it.
@Composable
fun ImagePickerScreen() {
    val viewModel : ImageViewModel by viewModels
}

I've attempted to import all dependencies, but the delegate function still isn't importing.

You can only use by viewModels in the Android View system, not with Jetpack Compose. In Compose you have the viewModel() function that you can use as follows:
@Composable
fun ImagePickerScreen(viewModel: ImageViewModel = viewModel()) {
    // or declare it in function body
    // val viewModel: ImageViewModel = viewModel()
}

You will need the following dependency in your build.gradle:
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.5")

If you use Navigation with a NavHost, this will return a ViewModel instance that is scoped to the current destination of the NavGraph.  Otherwise, the instance will be scoped to the Activity.
